# How to access google drive data when using google-colab in local runtime?

Tags: google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab, pydrive

I have tried using PyDrive to authenticate and get access of Google Drive.
I followed every step in here, https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html.

After downloading and renaming “client_secrets.json”, where should I put or use this file in Jupyter notebook environment, in order to access google-drive in google-colab for local runtime?

I am getting error, InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file while saving PyDrive credentials.

In order to use Google Colab in 'local runtime'. 
You have to install Jupyter and related packages, that I have been able to do, as mentioned here https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html.

But how to access 'google-drive' now?